# Navigation and states inside ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to make an app where the first time you use it I save some information locally. My purpose is that when the next times a person open the app it will be shown another page.
The problem is that I don't know how to load a simple page (not a part like a template) from my controller function.

**Here my html**

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-content class="center" [....]
<button class="button button-calm button-full button-clear button-large" ng-click="saveAll(name, job)">
                <span style="font-size: 1.4em;">start</span>
              </button>
</ion-content>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    controller: "HomeCtrl",
    template: "<h1>Home page</h1>"
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/first')
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $localstorage, $location) {
  $scope.setName = function(name) {
    if (name) {
      $localstorage.set('name', name.toLowerCase());
      console.log(name);
    }
  }
  $scope.getName = function() {
    alert($localstorage.get('name'));
  }
  $scope.setJob = function(job) {
    if (name) {
      $localstorage.set('job', job.toLowerCase());
      console.log(job);
    }
  }
  $scope.getJob = function() {
    alert($localstorage.get('job'));
  }
  $scope.saveAll = function(name, job) {
    if (name) {
      $localstorage.set('name', name.toLowerCase());
      console.log(name);
    }
    if (job) {
      $localstorage.set('job', job.toLowerCase());
      console.log(job);
    }
    if (name && job) {
      $location.path("home");

    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate routes using:

```
$location.path('/home');
```

or:

```
$state.go('home');
```

So.. in your MainCtrl you could put something like this:

```
$scope.getName = function() {
    return $localstorage.get('name');
};

$scope.getJob = function() {
    return $localstorage.get('job');
};

var init = function(){
    if($scope.getName() && $scope.getJob()){
        $location.path('/home');
    }
};

init();
```

UPDATE:

Ionic has ui-router installed by default. [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Each route accept a **templateUrl** property. I don't know which is you folder structure so you need to change them to work correctly:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
    })    
    .state('first', {
      url: '/first',
      controller: 'FirstCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'first/first.html'
    })
    .state('second', {
      url: "/second",
      controller: "SecondCtrl",
      templateUrl: 'second/second.html'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/first');
})
```

Comment: thanks for this! However it doesn't change page even if in the URL I can see /#/home.. Am I doing wrong the state declaration? And how can I load a new html page instead of: template: "<h1>Home page</h1>"

Comment: I tried to make changes you suggest but it doesn't work, sorry but i'm new to ionic and i'd like to learn more about it! If I put my project on GitHub can you watch it to solve the problem?

Comment: Sure no problem. Commit there and send me an email with the link